# Linux command: How to 'find' only text files?

Tags: linux, search, find

After a few searches from Google, what I come up with is:

```
find my_folder -type f -exec grep -l "needle text" {} \; -exec file {} \; | grep text
```

which is very unhandy and outputs unneeded texts such as mime type information. Any better solutions? I have lots of images and other binary files in the same folder with a lot of text files that I need to search through.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, but I stumbled across it and thought I'd share my method which I have found to be a very fast way to use `find` to find only non-binary files:

```
find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -print
```

The `-I` option to grep tells it to immediately ignore binary files and the `.` option along with the `-q` will make it immediately match text files so it goes very fast. You can change the `-print` to a `-print0` for piping into an `xargs -0` or something if you are concerned about spaces (thanks for the tip, @lucas.werkmeister!)

Also the first dot is only necessary for certain BSD versions of `find` such as on OS X, but it doesn't hurt anything just having it there all the time if you want to put this in an alias or something.

**EDIT**: As @ruslan correctly pointed out, the `-and` can be omitted since it is implied.

Comment: On Mac OS X, I need to change this to `find . -type f -exec grep -Il "" {} \;`.

Comment: This is better than peoro's answer because 1. it actually answers the question 2. It does not yield false positives 3. it is way more performant

Comment: You can also use `find -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -and -print` which has the advantage that it keeps the files in `find`; you can substitute `-print` with another `-exec` that is only run for text files. (If you let `grep` print the file names, you won’t be able to distinguish file names with newlines in them.)

Comment: @lucas.werkmeister Good idea!

Comment: Unfortunately, if you have a large text file with very long lines, this will choke `grep` and consume a lot of memory.

Comment: @NathanS.Watson-Haigh It shouldn't, because it should be matching text files immediately. Do you have a specific use case you can share?

Comment: I can assume you @histumness that I do have a file on which this happens. Whether it's a "valid" file is another question as I think from memory it may also not have had an EOL character! :)

Comment: I didn't know you could use the result of an exec statement in a conditional. Very nice.

Comment: `find . -type f -exec grep -Il . {} +` is much faster. Drawback is that it cannot be extended by another `-exec` as @lucas.werkmeister suggested

Comment: @Henning Oh good call. I didn't know about the `+` option to `find`. Very nice.

Comment: `find . -type f -exec grep -Il . {} +` brought binaries to me. Thanks!

Comment: `-and` can be omitted here, since it's the default operator (e.g. you didn't use it between `-type` and `-exec`).

Comment: @Henning I did some tests with `time` in a folder with ~200000 text files and many other files. (My ~/Downloads folder.) I did not see any obvious non-text files with either method, but did not look too closely.

`find . -type f -exec grep -Il . {} +` took 42.3 seconds.

`find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -print` took 22.7 **minutes**.

So I strongly recommend the first where possible. Running it again after the previous two commands took less than 10 seconds.

Comment: This command did not work for me. I've got large amount of raw binary images (custom format: one byte - one pixel, no compression, no headers or other embedded metainformation), many of them were listed.

Comment: What about if you're not using `grep`?

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you.

Performance suggestion:
all the forms of find that use -exec will fork a grep process for every file, which is slow.  Following will run much faster:
   `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -Iq ""`

Comment: This variant doesn't print the files with permission errors: `find . -type f 2>&- -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -print`

Answer (score 11):

Based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9806944/grep-only-text-files) :

`grep -rIl "needle text" my_folder`

Answer (score 10):

Why is it unhandy? If you need to use it often, and don't want to type it every time just define a bash function for it:

```
function findTextInAsciiFiles {
    # usage: findTextInAsciiFiles DIRECTORY NEEDLE_TEXT
    find "$1" -type f -exec grep -l "$2" {} \; -exec file {} \; | grep text
}
```

put it in your `.bashrc` and then just run:

```
findTextInAsciiFiles your_folder "needle text"
```

whenever you want.

---

**EDIT** to reflect OP's edit:

if you want to cut out mime informations you could just add a further stage to the pipeline that filters out mime informations. This should do the trick, by taking only what comes before `:`: `cut -d':' -f1`:

```
function findTextInAsciiFiles {
    # usage: findTextInAsciiFiles DIRECTORY NEEDLE_TEXT
    find "$1" -type f -exec grep -l "$2" {} \; -exec file {} \; | grep text | cut -d ':' -f1
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if "grep text" is accurate enough to get exactly all text files - I mean, is there any text file types that have no 'text' in the string of its mime type description?

Comment: @kavoir.com: yes. From `file` manual: "Users depend on knowing that all the readable files in a directory have the word ‘text’ printed."

Comment: Wouldn't it be a bit more clever to search for text files before grepping, instead of grepping and then filtering out text files?

Comment: `/proc/meminfo`, `/proc/cpuinfo` etc. are text files, but `file /proc/meminfo` says `/proc/meminfo: empty`. I wonder if 'empty' should be tested in addition to 'text', but not sure if also other types could report 'empty'.

Comment: "Why is it unhandy?" - "outputs unneeded texts". This answer does not sove that.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: uh? OP added "and outputs unneeded texts such as mime type information" later, modifying the question, and this answer was modified as well adding `cut` to the pipeline in order to only get the data OP's interested about. I'm not getting your point...

Comment: Option -q should be added to the first grep to avoid "unneeded texts"

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 file | grep -P text | cut -d: -f1 | xargs grep -Pil "search"
```

This is unfortunately not space save. Putting this into bash script makes it a bit easier.

This is space safe:

```
#!/bin/bash
#if [ ! "$1" ] ; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <search>";
    exit
fi

find . -type f -print0 \
  | xargs -0 file \
  | grep -P text \
  | cut -d: -f1 \
  | xargs -i% grep -Pil "$1" "%"
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues in your script: 1. what if a binary file is named `text.bin`? 2. What if a filename contains a `:`?

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing this:

```
# find . |xargs file {} \; |grep "ASCII text"
```

If you want empty files too:

```
#  find . |xargs file {} \; |egrep "ASCII text|empty"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simplified version with extended explanation for beginners like me who are trying to learn how to put more than one command in one line.

If you were to write out the problem in steps, it would look like this:

```
// For every file in this directory
// Check the filetype
// If it's an ASCII file, then print out the filename
```

To achieve this, we can use three UNIX commands: `find`, `file`, and `grep`.

`find` will check every file in the directory.

`file` will give us the filetype. In our case, we're looking for a return of 'ASCII text'

`grep` will look for the keyword 'ASCII' in the output from `file`

So how can we string these together in a single line? There are multiple ways to do it, but I find that doing it in order of our pseudo-code makes the most sense (especially to a beginner like me).

`find ./ -exec file {} ";" | grep 'ASCII'`

Looks complicated, but not bad when we break it down:

`find ./` = look through every file in this directory. The `find` command prints out the filename of any file that matches the 'expression', or whatever comes after the path, which in our case is the current directory or `./`

The most important thing to understand is that everything after that first bit is going to be evaluated as either True or False. If True, the file name will get printed out. If not, then the command moves on.

`-exec` = this flag is an option within the find command that allows us to use the result of some other command as the search expression. It's like calling a function within a function.

`file {}` = the command being called inside of `find`. The `file` command returns a string that tells you the filetype of a file. Regularly, it would look like this: `file mytextfile.txt`. In our case, we want it to use whatever file is being looked at by the `find` command, so we put in the curly braces `{}` to act as an empty variable, or parameter. In other words, we're just asking for the system to output a string for every file in the directory.

`";"` = this is required by `find` and is the punctuation mark at the end of our `-exec` command. See the manual for 'find' for more explanation if you need it by running `man find`.

`| grep 'ASCII'` = `|` is a pipe. Pipe take the output of whatever is on the left and uses it as input to whatever is on the right. It takes the output of the `find` command (a string that is the filetype of a single file) and tests it to see if it contains the string `'ASCII'`. If it does, it returns true.

NOW, the expression to the right of `find ./` will return true when the `grep` command returns true. Voila.

Comment: Upvote for sharing the detailed explanation about *why* the solution works, not just the solution itself.

Comment: Hear, hear. We need more detailed answers like this one on SO! Well done.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
$ grep -rl "needle text" my_folder | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -r -0 file | grep -e ':[^:]*text[^:]*$' | grep -v -e 'executable'
```

If you want the filenames without the file types, just add a final `sed` filter.

```
$ grep -rl "needle text" my_folder | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -r -0 file | grep -e ':[^:]*text[^:]*$' | grep -v -e 'executable' | sed 's|:[^:]*$||'
```

You can filter-out unneeded file types by adding more `-e 'type'` options to the last `grep` command.

EDIT:

If your `xargs` version supports the `-d` option, the commands above become simpler:

```
$ grep -rl "needle text" my_folder | xargs -d '\n' -r file | grep -e ':[^:]*text[^:]*$' | grep -v -e 'executable' | sed 's|:[^:]*$||'
```

Comment: silly me. Didn't notice recursive grep. as I understood it's actually quite fast even though a bit limited in many applications. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I've done it ...

1 . make a small script to test if a file is plain text
istext:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ "$(file -bi $1)" == *"file"* ]]
```

2 . use find as before

```
find . -type f -exec istext {} \; -exec grep -nHi mystring {} \;
```

Comment: I guess you mean `== *"text"* ]]`?

Comment: You may use the match-operator ` =~ "text" ]]` instead.

Answer (score 2):

I have two issues with histumness' answer:

- It only list text files. It does not actually search them as
  requested. To actually search, use

  ```
  find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -and -print0 | xargs -0 grep "needle text"
  ```
- It spawns a grep process for every file, which is very slow. A better solution is then

  ```
  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -IZl . | xargs -0 grep "needle text"
  ```

  or simply

  ```
  find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -I "needle text"
  ```

  This only takes 0.2s compared to 4s for solution above (2.5GB data / 7700 files), i.e. **20x faster**.

Also, nobody cited [ag, the Silver Searcher](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) or [ack-grep](http://beyondgrep.com/)¸as alternatives. If one of these are available, they are much better alternatives:

```bash
ag -t "needle text"    # Much faster than ack
ack -t "needle text"   # or ack-grep
```

As a last note, **beware of false positives** (binary files taken as text files). I already had false positive using either grep/ag/ack, so better list the matched files first before editing the files.

Comment: If you want speed, you want [`ugrep`](https://github.com/Genivia/ugrep) — consistently beating all benchmarks you can throw at it.

Comment: Also, for those using `ack`/`ag` because they really need to skip all those useless files listed in `.gitignore`,  just use `ugrep --ignore-files` (which uses `.gitignore` by default, but you can also pass it other files with globbed lists of files to ignore). And, of course, to ignore binary files, just use the `--ignore-binary` (or `-I`) option. And for more speed, you can use `ugrep-indexer`, a companion tool which will pre-index files in directories to speed up performance.

Comment: @GwynethLlewelyn I knew ripgrep, but didn't know about ugrep. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

Although it is an old question, I think this info bellow will add to the quality of the answers here.

When ignoring files **with the executable bit** set, I just use this command:

```
find . ! -perm -111
```

To keep it from recursively enter into other directories:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 ! -perm -111
```

No need for *pipes* to mix lots of commands, just the powerful plain *find* command.

- Disclaimer: it is not **exactly** what OP asked, because it doesn't check if the file is *binary* or not. It will, for example, filter out *bash script* files, that are *text* themselves but have the **executable bit set**.

That said, I hope this is useful to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I do it this way:
1) since there're too many files (~30k) to search thru, I generate the text file list daily for use via crontab using below command:

```
find /to/src/folder -type f -exec file {} \; | grep text | cut -d: -f1 > ~/.src_list &
```

2) create a function in .bashrc:

```
findex() {
    cat ~/.src_list | xargs grep "$*" 2>/dev/null
}
```

Then I can use below command to do the search:

```
findex "needle text"
```

HTH:)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer xargs

```
find . -type f | xargs grep -I "needle text"
```

if your filenames are weird look up using the -0 options:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep -I "needle text"
```

Answer (score 0):

- bash example to serach text "eth0" in /etc in all text/ascii files

grep eth0 $(find /etc/ -type f -exec file {} \; | egrep -i "text|ascii" | cut -d ':' -f1)

Comment: Lacks any code formatting (can't suggest an edit).

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in finding any file type by their magic bytes using the awesome `file` utility combined with power of `find`, this can come in handy:

```
$ # Let's make some test files
$ mkdir ASCII-finder
$ cd ASCII-finder
$ dd if=/dev/urandom of=binary.file bs=1M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB, 1.0 MiB) copied, 0.009023 s, 116 MB/s
$ file binary.file
binary.file: data
$ echo 123 > text.txt
$ # Let the magic begin
$ find -type f -print0 | \
    xargs -0 -I @@ bash -c 'file "$@" | grep ASCII &>/dev/null && echo "file is ASCII: $@"' -- @@
```

**Output:**

```
file is ASCII: ./text.txt
```

Legend: `$` is the interactive shell prompt where we enter our commands

You can modify the part after `&&` to call some other script or do some other stuff inline as well, i.e. if that file contains given string, cat the entire file or look for a secondary string in it.

**Explanation:**

- `find` items that are files
- Make `xargs` feed each item as a line into one liner `bash`
  command/script
- `file` checks type of file by magic byte, `grep` checks if ASCII
  exists, if so, then after `&&` your next command executes.
- `find` prints results `null` separated, this is good to escape
  filenames with spaces and meta-characters in it.
- `xargs` , using `-0` option, reads them `null` separated, `-I @@`
  takes each record and uses as positional parameter/args to bash
  script.
- `--` for `bash` ensures whatever comes after it is an argument even
  if it starts with `-` like `-c` which could otherwise be interpreted
  as bash option

If you need to find types other than ASCII, simply replace `grep ASCII` with other type, like `grep "PDF document, version 1.4"`

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f | xargs file | grep "ASCII text" | awk -F: '{print $1}'
```

Use find command to list all files, use file command to verify they are text (not tar,key), finally use awk command to filter and print the result.

Comment: Not all text file contains only ASCII characters, Unicode characters are possible, e.g. `file` report `UTF8 text` for those text files.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep --recursive --binary-files=without-match --files-with-matches --no-messages . | xargs -d '\n' realpath
```

Has worked satisfyingly thus far — I'm piping the `grep` results to `realpath` in order to receive the absolute paths. `xargs -d '\n'` handles potential spaces in filenames and paths.

Replace `.` with the desired search path when necessary.

Answer (score -4):

How about this

```
 find . -type f|xargs grep "needle text"
```

Comment: This doesn't look for `"needle text"`

Comment: @Navi: the example OP provided only finds files containing `"needl text"`

Comment: @Navi: now it doesn't looks for text files anymore: if a binary file contains `"needle text"` it would be found

Comment: Why am I even listening to you?

Comment: @Navi: your one-liner does not check file types and also has major issues with whitespace in filenames...