# grep only text files

Tags: bash, grep

```
find . -type f | xargs file | grep text | cut -d':' -f1 | xargs grep -l "TEXTSEARCH" {}
```

it's a good solution? for find TEXTSEARCH recursively in only textual files

Answer (score 270, accepted):

You can use the `-r`(recursive) and `-I`(ignore binary) options in `grep`:

```
$ grep -rI "TEXTSEARCH" .
```

> - `-I`     Process a binary file as if it did not contain matching data; this is equivalent to the `--binary-files=without-match` option.
> - `-r`     Read all files under each directory, recursively; this is equivalent to the `-d recurse` option.

Comment: No, this one can not ignore special file, like unix socket

Answer (score 9):

If you know what the file extension is that you want to search, then a very simple way to search all *.txt files from the current dir, recursively through all subdirs, case insensitive:

```bash
grep -ri --include=*.txt "sometext" *
```

Comment: The `--include` flag needs a glob pattern enclosed in quotes. This as it is won't work, more like this: `--include="*.txt"`.

Answer (score 7):

Another, less elegant solution than kevs, is, to chain -exec commands in find together, without xargs and cut:

```
find . -type f -exec bash -c "file -bi {} | grep -q text" \; -exec grep TEXTSEARCH {} ";"
```

Comment: Look at the next answer. Do not use this one.

Comment: Which problem do you see with this one?

Comment: it is complex and inefficient. The built-in grep tool is able to solve the question with a single flag. This answer may do the job, but it is a poor solution, in light of the other one's existence. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: It depends much on the number of files to search and their size. Often it isn't of interest if a search runs for 0.01s or 0.001s. Still, kevs answer is much faster to type, more easy to remember and even if you don't remember any of them more easy to look up. However, I guess my command shows how to chain filters with find which is a useful thing to see, so I don't like to delete it, even While I upvoted kevs solution.

Comment: Not all versions of grep support `-I`

Comment: This answer is more flexible and useful because the result of find command can be filtered by mime type.

Comment: There could be differences in performance over remote filesystems, and this answer is more flexible in terms of what precise kinds of files should be searched.

The other solution is definitely preferred, but this is an interesting tool for someone's toolbox.