# Find if null exists in csv file

Tags: bash, csv, sed, null

I have a csv file. The file has some anomalies as it contains some unknown characters.

The characters appear at line 1535 in popular editors (images attached below). The sed command in the terminal for this linedoes not show anything.

```
$ sed '1535!d' sample.csv
"sample_id","sample_column_text_1","sample_"sample_id","sample_column_text_1","sample_column_text_2","sample_column_text_3"
```

However below are the snapshots of the file in various editors.

**Sublime Text**
[image]

**Nano**
[image]

**Vi**
[image]

The directory has various csv files that contain this character/chain of characters.

I need to write a bash script to determine the files that have such characters. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use `grep '[^[:print:]]'` to find files or lines that contain non-printable characters.

Comment: This command is stuck up on my terminal...not moving forward. What does this command do and how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is from;

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/how-to-check-for-null-characters-in-file-509377/

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

my $null_found = 0;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    if ( ! open(F, "<$file") ) {
        warn "couldn't open $file for reading: $!\n";
        next;
    }

    while(<F>) {
        if ( /\000/ ) {
            print "detected NULL at line $. in file $file\n";
            $null_found = 1;
            last;
        }
    }
    close(F);
}

exit $null_found;
```

If it works as desired, you can save it to a file, nullcheck.pl and make it executable;

```
chmod +x nullcheck.pl
```

It seems to take an array of files names as input, but will fail if it finds in any, so I'd only pass in one at a time. The command below is used to run the script.

```
for f in $(find . -type f -exec grep -Iq . {} \; -and -print) ; do perl ./nullcheck.pl $f || echo "$f has nulls"; done
```

The above find command is lifted from [Linux command: How to 'find' only text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767396/linux-command-how-to-find-only-text-files)

Comment: Elegant solution!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `tr` :

`grep '\000' filename to find if the files contain the \000 characters.`

You can use this to remove NULL and make it non-NULL file :
`tr < file-with-nulls -d '\000' > file-without-nulls`