# How to search for text files containing a text string on a linux system

Tags: linux

I want to collect and move all text files that contain the string “MEDIUM” that are present in my subdirectories on a linux system, to a new folder called MEDIUM_files.   I am able to collect all files containing MEDIUM by using

```
ls *MEDIUM*
```

but I only want the text files.

All the files contain MEDIUM, but they also differ in number.  For example the file name contain different numbers at the end such as "MEDIUM_30_1.txt" or  through "MEDIUM_1850_20.txt"

How can I specify a file type as well as containing a string?

Comment: How do you define a text file? By having it only contain a set of characters?
In whichever case, you may find this useful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/13659891/3721256

Comment: I am defining a text file by having the suffix .txt

Comment: So `*MEDIUM*.txt` ?

Comment: When you say "files containing a string", do you mean the file **name** contains the string, or the file **contents**?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: And if the filename always starts with `MEDIUM`, it should be `MEDIUM*.txt`

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I hadn't heard of SuperUser, I will post my question there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux command: How to 'find' only text files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767396/linux-command-how-to-find-only-text-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f | grep MEDIUM | grep '\.txt$' | xargs -I{} mv {} MEDIUM_files
```